# Pinterest scraping pagination parameters

Tags: php, pagination, web-scraping, pinterest

I am scraping pinterest.com, because they don't want to approve my application to use their official API. I am able to scrape almost all data: pins, boards, likes, followers, etc. But usually Pinterest.com gives data only about 50 first items.
I have analyzed server's answers when I scrolling down page and it there is dynamic loaded by ajax results.

Request to server is something like [this](https://www.pinterest.com/resource/UserPinsResource/get/?source_url=%2Fhumor%2Fpins&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22username%22%3A%22humor%22%2C%22bookmarks%22%3A%5B%22Pz8yLjE0MjY5NzYyODkuNzAzNzU2MTY4NzMzNDgzfDkzYjRlY2VlOWNjZTUyOTQ3OTViZWFjZjk2ZTgyMDNmMzcyMjIxN2JiNTVlNTg1MmExNWJiMjM4ZWNiY2U0MmQ%3D%22%5D%2C%22is_own_profile_pins%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&_=1469685347815)

This request's parameters are:

_
1469685347816
data

```
{"options":{"username":"humor","bookmarks":["Pz8yLjE0MDk3NDc4MTkuNzAzNzU2MTY3NTQ0ODYwfGIyN2Y2NTlmYzQ0Y2U0ZGU1YjY5ZjNkYTlkMzM3ODEyNzI5M2FiYWFhYmI3NDBlODM3ZDJkZGU2MmRhOGYwN2E
="],"is_own_profile_pins":true},"context":{}}
module_path 
App>UserProfilePage>UserProfileContent>Grid>GridItems>Pin(component_type=0, show_board=true, use_native_image_width
=true, squish_giraffe_pins=none, show_pinner=true, show_pinned_from=false, resource=PinResource(main_module_name
=null, id=703756168806524))
source_url  
/humor/pins
```

Several more request's parameters (next dynamic results of the same [page](https://www.pinterest.com/humor/pins)):
_
1469685347818
data

```
{"options":{"username":"humor","bookmarks":["Pz8yLjEzODk5NjczMDYuNzAzNzU2MTY2MjY4MjIxfDkxYzlkMDFhMDMzZmM3M2JlZTkxYzAxODAxOTNmMGM2YWVhOGE4ODFlNjVmYjkwZmI1NDkyYjBhNDk3OGM4NzA
="],"is_own_profile_pins":true},"context":{}}
module_path 
App>UserProfilePage>UserProfileContent>Grid>GridItems>Pin(show_pinner=true, show_pinned_from=false, show_board
=true, squish_giraffe_pins=none, use_native_image_width=true, component_type=0, resource=PinResource
(id=194428908887545178, main_module_name=null))
source_url  
/humor/pins
```

_
1469685347819
data

```
{"options":{"username":"humor","bookmarks":["Pz8yLjEzODAzOTEwNzYuNzAzNzU2MTY1NjQ5NzQ0fDhkYzUwNjA3MmE3MGYzNTM3Y2MwYTBkYzIxMjY2Y2E5Y2NiMGM3MDk5ZjU1YjYxM2QwYzYzOGZiNWI2YzE4MWQ
="],"is_own_profile_pins":true},"context":{}}
module_path 
App>UserProfilePage>UserProfileContent>Grid>GridItems>Pin(show_pinner=true, show_pinned_from=false, show_board
=true, squish_giraffe_pins=none, use_native_image_width=true, component_type=0, resource=PinResource
(id=194428908887545178, main_module_name=null))
source_url  
/humor/pins
```

I understood that 1469685347819, 1469685347818 most likely the pagination parameters, but I don't know how to correctly generate them to retrieve needed pagination results. Looks like that 1469685347 part is timestamp when page is loaded and last to digits are some pagination parameters.

Comment: Thanks A.Danischewski. Can you please describe it in more details, because I have tried to get "bookmarks" value from initial page but without a successfull. If you know the answer practically, not only theoretically, please make it as answer with screenshots, not as small comment. It will help me very much. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried like you wrote, but I didn't find "feed". Also not always initial page contains the value of "bookmarks" and  I also don't know where to find it.

Comment: I have tried it for board pins (like https://www.pinterest.com/ambreninja/chara-design/) - it works fine, thank you. Can you please also advice me how to make it working for profile pins page, like https://www.pinterest.com/love/pins/ ? Because this page's https://www.pinterest.com/love/pins/ source code  doesn't contain a correct value of "bookmarks" (only value bookmarks": ["-end-"] which I cannot use). Thanks.

Comment: For the other protocols you can possibly search out the old API and see if you can figure it out from there. They don't publish their v4 API, you can try to get a key but it's difficult. It's good to learn to reverse protocols -- just do what you have done for the boards except capture all the calls (don't use filter "feed") on scrolls then watch the xhr's and compare them to see what's changing (it may help to take the curl and break the options starting with a space dash (" -") into newlines then use a tool such as `meld` to do side-by-side comparisons.

Comment: Another technique you may find useful is to reduce until breaking. E.g. capture 5 xhr's that correspond to the love/pins inifinity scrolls -- xhr1.curl .. xhr5.curl. Then take the first curl in a text editor and start removing curl headers to see if you get back the same data, until it breaks. Then put back what broke it and continue until you find out what is necessary, repeat for all curls.